# When to send metadeta and stream of next song?

Tags: java, audio, shoutcast, icecast

I'm writing an `Icecast` source. When dealing with one song, everything works fine. I send the `Icecast` header information, the metadeta and then the file stream.

My source needs to handle playlists. At the moment, once my application is finished writing the stream for `Song A`, it sends the metadeta for `Song B` and then sends the stream for `Song B`. After `Song B` is finished writing to Icecast, I send the metadeta for `Song C` and the file stream for `Song C` etc.

This issue with my current set up, is that every time the next song is sent (metadeta + stream), the icecast buffer resets. I'm assuming it is probably whenever a new metadeta update is sent.

How do I detect when one song (on `Icecast`) is finished so that I may send a new metadeta (and stream)?

**EDIT:** When I listen to the `Icecast` stream using a client (like `VLC`), I notice it does not even play the full song, even though the full song is being sent to and received by `Icecast`. It skips parts in the song. I'm thinking maybe there is a buffer limit on `Icecast`, and it is resetting the buffer when it reaches this limit? Should I then, purposely slow down the rate at which the source sends data to `Icecast`?

**EDIT:** I have determined that the issue is the rate at which I send the audio data to the `Icecast` server. At the moment, I am not slowing down the data transfer. I need to slow down this transfer so that the speed at which I write the audio data to `Icecast` is more/less the same speed at which a client would read the stream. I am thinking this rate would actually be the `bitrate`. If this is the case, I need to have the `OutputStream` thread sleep for an amount of time before sending the next chunk of data. How long do I make it sleep, assuming this is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continuously flush data to Icecast, the buffer is immediately filled and written over circularly.  Most clients (especially VLC) will put backpressure on their stream during playback causing the TCP window size to drop to zero, meaning the server should not send any more data.  When this happens, the server has to wait.  Once the window size is increased again, the position at which the client was streaming before has been flushed out of the buffer by several minutes of audio, causing a glitch (or commonly, a disconnect).

As you have suspected, you must control the rate at which data is sent to Icecast.  This rate must be at the same rate of playback.  While this is approximated by the bitrate, it often isn't exact.  The best way to handle this is to actually play back this audio programmatically while sending to the codec.  You will need to do this soon anyway when encoding with several codecs at several bitrates.